# Prove that: $\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}}=\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

A weird definite integral that tends to $\pi/4$:

$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\pi/2}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}} \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$$

This is based off of approximations from the Integral and Wolfram definite integral calculators online. I have no idea how to solve this...

Try to prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $t^2=\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2$. Then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}} \, dx=\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\frac{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-t^2\right)}{t}\frac{t}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-t^2}} \, dt=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\dfrac{\cos^2(t^2)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-t^2}}} \, dt.$$
So,
$$2I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\dfrac{\sin^2(x^2)+\cos^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}} \, dx=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}} \, dx=\lim_{x \to \sqrt\frac{\pi}{2}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}\Big|_{0}^{t}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Comment: Much simpler than mine ! (+1)

Answer (score 3):

$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}}\, dx$$
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{\pi -2 t}{2} }\quad \implies \quad I=\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\cos(t)^2 } {\sqrt{t(\pi-2t) } }\,dt$$

Using series
$$\cos(t)^2=1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \,\frac{ 2^{2 n-1}}{(2 n)!}\,t^{2n}$$
Using the Gaussian hypergeometric function
$$\int \frac {t^{2n}}{\sqrt{t(\pi-2t) } }\,dt=\frac{t^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},2
   n+\frac{1}{2};2 n+\frac{3}{2};\frac{2 t}{\pi
   }\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac {t^{2n}}{\sqrt{t(\pi-2t) } }\,dt= \left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{2 n+\frac{1}{2}}\,\,\frac{\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n+1)}$$
All of the above makes
$$I \sqrt 2=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}+\frac 12\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \pi^{2n}\frac{\Gamma \left(2 n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma (2 n+1)}=\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{2}}$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}}\, dx=\frac \pi 4$$

**Edit**

We could go beyond for any $k\geq 2$

$$J_k=\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}}{\frac{\sin^2(x^2)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}}\, dx$$ $$J_k=\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{k}}\right)+\frac 14\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!} B_{\frac{2}{k}}\left(\frac{4n+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Not only the series is alternting but the summands are really small.

**For the fun**

Using my favored $1400^+$ years old approximation of the cosine function, there is an easy antiderivative and
$$I \sim \frac {64-\sqrt{1910+865 \sqrt{5}} } {8} \pi =0.784769$$ which is in a relative error of $0.08$%.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your last remark about the 1400+ year old approximation of cosine. Can you include a reference?

Comment: @JessicaK Have a look at  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_I%27s_sine_approximation_formula

Answer (score 2):

Putting $x\mapsto \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}  $ transforms the integral into
$$
I=\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{\sin ^2\left(x^2\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}dx= \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{\cos ^2\left(x^2\right)}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}}dx
$$
Averaging the two versions of $I$ yields
$$
I=\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}-x^2}} d x=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sin ^{-1} \frac{x}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}\right]_0^{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}}=\frac{\pi}{4}
$$